# Get exit code and stderr from subprocess call

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read up on the functions provided by subprocess - call, check_call, check_output, and understand how each works and differs in functionality from one another.  I am currently using check_output, so I can have access to the stdout, and used "try block" to catch the exception, as follows:

```
# "cmnd" is a string that contains the command along with it's arguments. 
try:
    cmnd_output = check_output(cmnd, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True, timeout=3, universal_newlines=True);                         
except CalledProcessError:                                                                                                   
    print("Status : FAIL")                                                                                                   
print("Output: \n{}\n".format(cmnd_output))
```

The issue I am running into is when an exception is thrown, "cmnd_output" is not initialized and don't have access to stderr, and I get the following error message:

```
print("Output: \n{}\n".format(cmnd_output))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cmnd_output' referenced before assignment
```

I think thats because the exception causes the "check_output" to bail immediately without any further processing, aka assignment to "cmnd_output", in the try block.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Is there any way I can get access to stderr (it's ok if it's sent to stout) and have access to the exit code. I can manually check for pass/fail based on exit code with out the exception being throuwn.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Try this version:

```
import subprocess
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        cmnd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, timeout=3,
        universal_newlines=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    print("Status : FAIL", exc.returncode, exc.output)
else:
    print("Output: \n{}\n".format(output))
```

This way you will print the output only if the call was successful.
In case of a [`CalledProcessError`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) you print the return code and the output.

Comment: I am getting this error : `ret = subprocess.check_output(cmd , stderr=STDOUT,shell=True)`
`NameError: global name 'STDOUT' is not defined`

Comment: Perfect! Do not forget `stderr=STDOUT`, when you try this approach

Comment: `timeout` is used because the code from OP used it. Obviously everything except `cmnd` is optional.

Comment: I think this approach will mix the output to stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 82):

The accepted solution covers the case in which you are ok mixing `stdout` and `stderr`, but in cases in which the child process (for whatever reason) decides to use `stderr` IN ADDITION to `stdout` for a non failed output (i.e. to output a non-critical warning), then the given solution may not desirable.

For example, if you will be doing additional processing on the output, like converting to JSON, and you mix in the `stderr`, then the overall process will fail since the output will not be pure JSON because of the added `stderr` output.

I've found the following to work in that case:

```
cmd_args = ... what you want to execute ...

pipes = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#If you are using python 2.x, you need to include shell=True in the above line
std_out, std_err = pipes.communicate()

if pipes.returncode != 0:
    # an error happened!
    err_msg = "%s. Code: %s" % (std_err.strip(), pipes.returncode)
    raise Exception(err_msg)

elif len(std_err):
    # return code is 0 (no error), but we may want to
    # do something with the info on std_err
    # i.e. logger.warning(std_err)

# do whatever you want with std_out
# i.e. json.loads(std_out)
```

Comment: Very useful. This is my use case as well. stdout is used by my target as more of a log output than an error output. By the way, can you comment on the necessity of providing `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`? I've seen other posts doing it without the additional pipe and I'm not sure why.

Comment: For python 2.7 at least this crashes unless you add shell=True to the Popen

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I also needed a `.decode("utf-8")` after the err's as they are returned in bytes for some reason.

Answer (score 23):

Both of the proposed solutions either mix the stdout/stderr, or use `Popen` which isn't quite as simple to use as `check_output`. However, you can accomplish the same thing, and keep stdout/stderr separate, while using `check_output` if you simply *capture stderr* by using a pipe:

```
import sys
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_output(cmnd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print('exit code: {}'.format(e.returncode))
    print('stdout: {}'.format(e.output.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())))
    print('stderr: {}'.format(e.stderr.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())))
```

In this example, since we captured stderr, it's available in the exception's `stderr` attribute (without capturing with the pipe, it would just be `None`).

Comment: This solution requires python >= 3.5

Comment: I'm not a Python dev, so forgive the potential ignorance, but the Python docs sound like they suggest _not_ doing [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output): `Note: Do not use stderr=PIPE with this function as that can deadlock based on the child process error volume. Use Popen with the communicate() method when you need a stderr pipe.`

Comment: @Mike Popen with communicate() will also explode if you have too much output because there's no way to iteratively process both streams. Essentially, if you ever wanted to do something similar to what `tee` command does, that's, by and large, impossible in Python w/o a lot of dance with file descriptors, and doing all the work through system calls. The `subprocess` API is defective by design.

Comment: Specifically the thing that is missing from earlier versions is `CalledProcessError.stderr`. Previous versions only have `returncode`, `cmd` and `output`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, and the following worked for me:

```
    try:
        with open ("vtcstderr.out", "w") as file:
            rawOutput = subprocess.check_output(
                command,
                stderr=file,
                shell=True
            )
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
        # this is the stdout
        rawOutput = error.output
    
    with open ("vtcstderr.out", "r") as file:
        # this is the stderr
        errorLines = file.readlines()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

why not initialize the varible cmnd_output before the try statement? That way it will work the way you expect it to.
Following line would work, just add it above try statement :

```
cmnd_output = ''
```

Comment: I need cmnd_output to be initialized by the content of stdout (and also stderr).  This would happen under most cases except when the exit code of the program is non-zero.

Comment: Exactly, so in case there is an exception your code would print the exception and you won't have anything in the variable. But, when it runs normally(no exceptions) you would get the values of cmnd_output.