# Python "os.popen...read()" does not work when running as a service

Tags: python

I have created a service to run a python script at boot.

Service File Info:

Name: `robovacuum.service`

Location: `/lib/systemd/system/robovacuum.service`

Contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Python script that listens for MQTT commands for the RoboRock Vacuum
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=tovar
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/tovar/mqttToPythonCommands.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Python script info:

Name: `mqttToPythonCommands.py`

Code:

```
..
currCommand = 'mirobo --ip 192.168.1.100 --token tokenKeyHere start'
cmdResult = os.popen(currCommand).read()
if "Error:" not in cmdResult:
  #command was successful do more stuff
else:
  #there was an error

..
```

When running the python script from the terminal the `cmdResult` returns something like this: `"Vacuum has started"`.

But when I am running the script as a service the `cmdResult` comes back blank and therefore the rest of my code doesn't process correctly. Can someone give me an idea of what I am doing wrong here or what I should be using in place when running as a service? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the errors are being printed to `stderr`. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/27661481/235354

Comment: How about `p=subprocess.popen(currCommand); cmdResult, err = p.communicate()`?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I will have to check out these suggestions later tonight. Will keep you posted.