# How to distinguish between subprocess errors in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm working on a terminal that can call other programs like any other terminal. I'm using subprocess for it, on Windows.
I'm running into 2 issues.

**First:**
Currently, I'm using OSError for all errors raised when using subprocess.Popen.

The code for it is here:

```py
try:
    subprocess.Popen([command])
except OSError:
    print("'" + command[0] + "' is not recognised as a command, program or bterm file.")
```

When I type `python`, it opens command-line python correctly.
When I type `asdfa`, it returns the error.
The problem is, when I type `python non-existent-file.py` I get the same error, when the child argument was the issue.

I want the terminal to return `(null): can't open file 'test': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` like when it's called from cmd or bash.

How can I distinguish between these 2 errors, while keeping my custom error message for when the file doesn't exist?

<strike>**Second:** Whenever I pass multi-word args into `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.call` I automatically get that error, which I don't get using `os.system()`</strike>

I don't want to use `os.system` because I can't raise custom errors with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849998/how-to-catch-exception-output-from-python-subprocess-check-output

Comment: @AkhilBatra Not quite, I still want my custom error to print when the file doesn't exist, instead of just returning an error from cmd

Comment: you can try redirecting subprocess output to stderr and catch error based on the return code. Similar to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198546/get-exit-code-and-stderr-from-subprocess-call

Comment: @AkhilBatra I get error code 2 both times when returning the error using ```except OSError as ex
print(ex)
```

Comment: That's a bummer.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions in subprocess calls:

Exceptions raised in the child process, before the new program has started to execute, will be re-raised in the parent. 
Additionally, the exception object will have one extra attribute called child_traceback, which is a string containing traceback information from the child’s point of view.

The most common exception raised is **OSError**. 
This occurs, for example, when trying to execute a non-existent file. Applications should prepare for OSError exceptions.

A **ValueError** will be raised if Popen is called with invalid arguments.

**check_call**() and **check_output**() will raise **CalledProcessError** if the called process returns a non-zero return code.

You can find more at:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#exceptions

As well as you can find the Exception Heirarchy at:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output("\\test.exe')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print("Something Fishy... returncode: " + e.returncode + ", output:\n" + e.output)
else:
    print("Working Fine:\n" + output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could test for the existence of the executable first with the help of `shutil.which`.

```py
if shutil.which(commands[0]):
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([commands])
    except OSError as err:
        print(err)
else:
    print("'{}' is not recognised as a command, program or bterm file.".format(commands[0])
```

The documentation has a great deal of info however: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html which may be helpful.

Edit: showed how to capture output, thanks to [Auxilor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11427550/auxilor)

Comment: you can capture the output with this


```python
except OSError as ex:
```


```python
print(ex)
```

Comment: problem is, with this one, you end up with everything inputted into something like cmd or python being treated as an input into my terminal