# Using subprocess.check_output to run flake8

Tags: python, subprocess, flake8

I am trying to make a basic linter script which I can run on Python files in the current directory. So far my script looks like this:

```
import subprocess
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subprocess.check_output(["black", "-l", "100", "./"])

    files = [f for f in listdir("./") if isfile(join("./", f))]
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            subprocess.check_output(["flake8", file])
```

I am wanting to run the code via the command line with a call such as *main.py*. Black performs fine and finds the *.py* files in the current directory and formats them without a problem. However, when trying to run a similar command with flake8, it also runs on children of the directory such as the *venv* folder which I am not interested in.

Therefore, the script includes a check to get the files in the current directory and then find the *.py* files. However, once I get those files, I cannot seem to use my flake8 command with subprocess.check_output. The error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linter.py", line 18, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output(["flake8", file], shell=False)
  File "C:\Users\calum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\calum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['flake8', 'flask_server_controller.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Could someone please explain the error and/or provide a solution to my problem. I would also like to add other linting tools to the script such as *pylint*, however, I am worried I will run into the same problem without understanding it properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run `'flake8 flask_server_controller.py'` yourself in console, to see the error. I assume you need to pass the full path to flake and make sure flake is in your env/path variable

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a tool that is actually suitable for this task, like a shell script?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Thanks for your reply. If I run the command above as suggested flake8 works on the file. There is no error, therefore, I don't think its a flake or env issue.

Comment: @tripleee No major reason. I have seen on a few other posts saying that shell script is not a good idea but as my experience is little, please feel free to provide an answer which uses it. I have tried to add the flag `shell=True` into `subprocess.check_output(["flake8", file], shell=True)`, however, this made no difference.

Comment: Check the path to the `flask_server_controller.py` or have a look at `stderr` as mentioned there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198546/get-exit-code-and-stderr-from-subprocess-call. `exit status 1` is definitely a 'response' from flake8.

Comment: `join("./",…)` doesn’t do anything.  `shell=True` does mostly bad things.  (Using a shell script as the entire program might or might not be an improvement.)

Comment: You can't pass a list with `shell=True` but I would advise against that here. Either replace the Python script with a shell script, or go all Python. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I looked at the link you suggested and adapted one of those answers. It works a treat. Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.check_output` is giving you that because of the `check_` aspect

this means that when the executable you're running returns nonzero (for example, `flake8` returns nonzero when it detects lint failures) an exception will be raised

To avoid this behaviour, I'd suggest using `subprocess.run` instead, and forwarding along the return code.  Something like this:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import sys


def main():
    ret = 0
    output = b''
    for filename in os.listdir('.'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            proc_ret = subprocess.run(
                ('flake8', filename),
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            )
            ret |= proc_ret.returncode
            output += proc_ret.stdout
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(output)
    return ret


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

Note that this is going to be *prohibitively* slow, you have to incur the startup cost of `flake8` for every file.

One way you can improve this is by passing all the filenames to flake8 at once:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import sys


def main():
    filenames = (fname for fname in os.listdir('.') if fname.endswith('.py'))
    proc_ret = subprocess.run(('flake8', *filenames), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(proc_ret.stdout)
    return proc_ret.returncode


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

but also this brings up another interesting point, why are you collecting the output at all? if you let the output go to stdout it will be printed automatically:

```py
import os
import subprocess


def main():
    filenames = (fname for fname in os.listdir('.') if fname.endswith('.py'))
    return subprocess.call(('flake8', *filenames))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

and hmmm, you probably don't need to do this at all since `flake8` has its own inclusion / exclusion code -- you probably just want to configure `exclude` properly

```
# setup.cfg / tox.ini / .flake8
[flake8]
# for example, exclude recursing into the venv
exclude = venv
```

and then you can use `flake8 .` as normal

(disclaimer: I am the current maintainer of flake8)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to solve the problem looking at a different post but some of the points you have made I will change and implement. Thanks for your help :)