# Python subprocess.call() keep subprocess window open after an Exception

Tags: python, exception, process, subprocess

I'm writing a script that will run another script and restart it either after 2 hours or after an error. There is no way to see the exception because the subprocess script closes immediately after an error. I'm looking for a method that will keep the subprocess window open only after an Exception, but not after a TimeoutExpired. Running Windows 10 btw.

Code:

```
from subprocess import call, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, TimeoutExpired

fail_count = 0
while(fail_count < 10):
    print("Starting: " + f"python {filename}")
    try:
        #    start in a new terminal window
        call(['python', filename], timeout=7200, creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    except TimeoutExpired as e:
        #    after 2 hours, close window and restart script
        print("Timeout")
        print(e)
        time.sleep(30)
    else:
        #    on exception, leave window open
        print("Error, leaving subprocess window open...")
        time.sleep(120)
        fail_count += 1
```

Comment: Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198546/get-exit-code-and-stderr-from-subprocess-call