# Log stderr of subprocess to log file

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

I am using `subprocess` to run a python script inside a different python script because each script needs its own version of Python. Lets call them `main.py` and `called_from_main.py`. In `main.py` I'm using `logging` module redirected to a file.

#### main.py

```
try:
    returned = subprocess.check_output(r'"C:\path\to\python.exe" "C:\path\to\called_from_main.py"')
    logger.info(returned)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
    logger.exception(error)
    raise RuntimeError("That did not work")
```

#### called_from_main.py

```
# just for simplicity, I need it to raise some error right now
raise Exception("Error occured in called_from_main")
```

Now when I run this, in the output log I see `ERROR: Command '"C:\path\to\python.exe" "C:\path\to\called_from_main.py"' returned non-zero exit status 1.` But I do not see the error message `Error occured in called_from_main` itself.
What I think I need to do (but don't know how) is to redirect stderr of the subprocess to my logger which is redirected to a file.

Comment: Check the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198546/get-exit-code-and-stderr-from-subprocess-call

Comment: @Gnurfos that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!