# subprocess.check_output arguments syntax for querying a mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, subprocess

I am looking into querying a mysql database through python, but I am not allowed to use any python connector for mysql. It seems that the subprocess.check_output function should be able to return a result, but so far I can't get any output.

In this database I have created a Schema (through MySQL Workbench) which I name here as "Mydatabase" as well as a table with some entries which I name here as "Mytable".

My code is:

```
==============

import subprocess

hostname = 'DESKTOP-XXXXXX' # taken from mysql status
port = '3306' # taken from mysql status
username = 'my_username_goes_here'
password = 'my_password_goes_here'
database = 'the_sql_database_name_goes_here'

result = subprocess.check_output(['mysql', hostname, port, username, database, 'SELECT * 
FROM Mydatabase.Mytable;'])

print result 

==============
```

When I run this I get:

"subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[....]' returned non-zero exit status 1

From python documentation I can't find what is the correct syntax for a connection with a mysql server so it is possible that something is odd with my syntax.

I would be extremely pleased if someone could tell me where to find the correct syntax for this to work.

Comment: I suspect that you will need additional quote marks around your query. Try '"SELECT * FROM Mydatabase.Mytable;"'

Comment: Hello! Thanks for thinking about it. Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Comment: If you run the command from a normal command prompt, do you get the same error?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the answer to this question to try to figure out what the error is caused by https://stackoverflow.com/a/16198668/2323393 It should allow you to capture the error message from mysql